# Using Spring Rest Controllers

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-data-mongodb

I have been experiencing some trouble using @RestController while trying to post something in my DB. My goal is to try to get a result that looks like this:

```
{   

    "postID": "5",

    "content": "testcontent",

    "time": "13.00",

    "gender": "Man"

}
```

while posting something like this in "localhost:port/posts" (using Postman):

```
{  

    "content": "testcontent",

    "time": "13.00",

    "gender": "Man"
}
```

**Post.java**

```
package bananabackend;

public class Post {

private final long id;
private String content;
private String time;
private String gender;  


// Constructor

public Post(long id, String content, String time, String gender) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
    this.time = time;
    this.gender = gender;
}

// Getters

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
```

**PostController.java**

```
package bananabackend;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import bananabackend.Post;


@RestController
public class PostController {    

private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

@RequestMapping(value="/posts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Post postInsert(@RequestParam String content, @RequestParam    String time, @RequestParam String gender) {
    return new Post(counter.incrementAndGet(), content, time, gender);
    }
}
```

**PostRepository.java**

```
package bananabackend;

import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "posts", path = "posts")
public interface PostRepository extends MongoRepository<Post, String> {


List<Post> findPostByContent(@Param("content") String content);

}
```

I get this error:

```
{

    "timestamp": 1460717792270,

    "status": 400,

    "error": "Bad Request",

    "exception":  
    "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",

    "message": "Required String parameter 'content' is not present",

    "path": "/posts"
}
```

I want to set an ID to every post made but it doesn't seem to work. I was trying to build my code similar to this guide:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: Well, you specifiy several RequestParams and dont send any. You should put everything inside an object and use `@RequestBody NewObj obj` instead on your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get request parameters those are sent in request body. Request parameters are the parameters that you send in URL.

Instead of using `@RequestParam ...` use `@RequestBody Post post` such as:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/posts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Post postInsert(@RequestBody Post post) {
    return new Post(counter.incrementAndGet(), post.getContent(), post.getTime(), post.getGender());
}
```

Also you need a default constructor in `Post` class.

Comment: I tried writing it like this:


    return new Post(counter.incrementAndGet(), post.getContent(), post.getTime(), post.getGender());

I get this:


    Could not read document: No suitable constructor found for type[simple type, class bananabackend.Post]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?

If I simply write it like you did the variables are not recognized since they are in Post.java, so I tried to get them.

Comment: Edited the code. Also need a default constructor in Post class to create the instance.